# why the mockito.when(jsonObjectSpy.put(...)).thenThrow(...), it actually changed the jsonObjectSpy

Tags: mockito

using mockito 3.8.0, Having a class Util:

```
class Util {
    static JSONObject addKeyToJson_booleanValue(@NonNull JSONObject jsonObject, @NonNull String key, boolean value) {
        try {
            System.out.println("+++ +++ enter addKeyToJson(), jsonObject:"+jsonObject+", key:"+key+", val:"+value);
            jsonObject.put(key, value);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            System.out.println("+++ +++ !!! exp addKeyToJson(), jsonObject:"+jsonObject+", key:"+key+", val:"+value+", ex:"+e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jsonObject;
    }
}
```

the test

```
@Test
    public void test_addKeyToJson_boolean_value() throws JSONException {
        JSONObject jsonObjectSpy = Mockito.spy(new JSONObject());
        Mockito.when(jsonObjectSpy.put(anyString(), anyBoolean())).thenThrow(new JSONException("!!! test forced exception"));
       
        JSONObject outputObject = Util.addKeyToJson_booleanValue(jsonObjectSpy, "null", true);
        assertEquals(0, outputObject.length()); //<=== fail
    }
```

It is under impression that the `Mockito.when(jsonObjectSpy.put(anyString(), anyBoolean())).thenThrow(new JSONException("!!! test forced exception"));` is a setup for it to throw when the `jsonObject.put("null", true)` is called, so the returned jsonObject should be still empty.

But the test failed and noticed when `addKeyToJson(@NonNull JSONObject jsonObject, @NonNull String key, boolean value)` is called the `jsonObjectSpy` has already had a pair of {"", false}.
The log

```
+++ +++ enter addKeyToJson(), jsonObject:{"":false}, key:null, val:true
+++ +++ !!! exp addKeyToJson(), jsonObject:{"":false}, key:null, val:true, ex:org.json.JSONException: !!! test forced exception
```

and it does throw the exception.
The question is why the

```
Mockito.when(jsonObjectSpy.put(anyString(), anyBoolean())).thenThrow(new JSONException("!!! test forced exception"));
```

actually puts the `{"":false}` in the `jsonObjectSpy`?

But it works fine with `Mockito.when(jsonObjectSpy.put(anyString(), any())).thenThrow(new JSONException("!!! fake exception"));` when the value is expecting a String.

```
static JSONObject addKeyToJson_stringValue(@NonNull JSONObject jsonObject, @NonNull String key, @NonNull String value) {
        try {
            jsonObject.put(key, value);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jsonObject;
    }

===

@Test
    public void test_addKeyToJson_stringValue() throws Exception {
        JSONObject jsonObjectSpy = Mockito.spy(new JSONObject());
        Mockito.when(jsonObjectSpy.put(anyString(), any())).thenThrow(new JSONException("!!! fake exception"));
        Util.addKeyToJson_stringValue(jsonObjectSpy, "key", "value");
        assertEquals(0, jsonObjectSpy.length());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

seems

```
Mockito.when(jsonObjectSpy.put(anyString(), any())).thenThrow(new JSONException("!!! fake exception"));
```

with `any()` will not actually put the key/value pair in the jsonObjectSpy, but using the `anyString()`, or `anyBoolean()` will put the key/value pair in the jsonObjectSpy.

have to do `jsonObjectSpy.remove(anyString())` after the `Mockito.when(jsonObjectSpy.put(anyString(), anyBoolean())).thenThrow(new JSONException("!!! fake exception"));` to make the jsonObjectSpy an empty one again.